# How to make immutable hdd mutable using vboxmanage

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to understand how VirtualBox makes drive immutable and then mutable again.

I can make a hdd `immutable` with following two commands

```
vboxmanage storageattach lvm01 --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none
vboxmanage storageattach lvm01 --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "/home/ostraaten/VirtualBox VMs/lvm01/lvm01_mvm01-disk1.vmdk" --mtype immutable
```

This seems to work. Changes to the VM will be gone after `poweroff` and `startvm`.

Making changes to a immutable VM is a less straightforward process.

I can reverse immutability using similar command now with `mtype` `normal`

```
vboxmanage storageattach lvm01 --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none
vboxmanage storageattach lvm01 --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "/home/ostraaten/VirtualBox VMs/lvm01/lvm01_mvm01-disk1.vmdk" --mtype normal
```

This seems to also work. Changes will still be there on `poweroff` and `startvm`.

Now the problem. It does not seem possible to keep those changes if we want to make the VM `immutable` again. So a VM can only be made `immutable` once. On making the VM `immutable` again - for the second time - VirtualBox will revert changes and go back to the state of the first immutable VM.

For sure a bug but I suppose there is a workaround for this problem. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround already

1. Export the VM.
2. Unregister the VM.
3. Import the VM.
4. Make the VM immutable.

```
vboxmanage export lvm01 --output lvm01.ova
vboxmanage unregistervm lvm01 --delete
vboxmanage import lvm01.ova
vboxmanage storageattach lvm01 --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none
vboxmanage storageattach lvm01 --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "/home/ostraaten/VirtualBox VMs/lvm01/lvm01_mvm01-disk1.vmdk" --mtype immutable
```